# Proving or disproving of a homomorphism between two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Can Someone help me with an example explaining general approach in proving or disproving of the existence of a non trivial homomorphism between two groups?

Comment: It seems to me that there is no general way to prove the existence of non-trivial homomorphism between two groups. One can consider that if $f$ is a homomorphism between given two groups then show that $\ker f$ is whole domain or $f=0$, but its proof depends on the properties of the two groups.

Comment: Actually I am trying to Prove that there is no non trivial homomorphism from the group (Q, +) to (Q∗ , ×), where
Q∗ = Q \ {0}  but I don't have any idea how to start.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ is divisible, whereas $\Bbb{Q}^\times$ is not. Let $f:\Bbb{Q}\to\Bbb{Q}^\times$ be a non-trivial homomorphism. Whataver $f(1)$ is, you can find some sufficiently large $n$ s.t. $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = f(1)^{1/n}$ is irrational. (You might find that $f(1)\neq 1$. In that case $f$ should be trivial.)

Comment: What do u mean by saying That Q is divisible but Q* is not. (Q,+)and (Q,*) are both groups of rational numbers but under different operations.

Comment: You might know what divisible group is. $\Bbb{Q}^\times$ is *not* divisible, i.e. there is $q\in \Bbb{Q}$ and a natural number $n$ s.t. $q \neq p^n$ for all rational $p$.

Comment: The fact that $\Bbb{Q}^\times$ does *not* give the direct proof that there is no non-trivial homomorphism between $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}^\times$, but it gives an motivation. I describe a proof in preceding comment.